# How to choose right cascade type for hibernate entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have bidirectional mapping `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`. In my entity `OneToMany`:

```java
@OneToMany(
   mappedBy = "announcementTemplate",
   cascade = CascadeType.MERGE
)
private List<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want only to add additional field `warehouses`, nothing more - I don't want to delete any `Warehouse` when `THIS` entity is removed. The question is what's the best approach in this case?

Should I use:

1. `CascadeType.ALL`
2. `CascadeType.MERGE`
3. without any `CascadeType`

As I said, I want only to add new field `warehouses` to be able to display them on the frontend (without additional fetching of warehouses from database)

Answer (score 1):

The `cascade` property of the `@OneToMany` annotation allows hibernate to identify which  [entity state](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc) should be propagated from a parent entity to a child.

Example:

Assuming that you have the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
class Parent
{
   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and then you do:

```java
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.children.add(new Child());
entityManager.persist(parent);
```

Due to the usage of `CascadeType.PERSIST` in `cascade` you can expect that a new child will be persisted together with parent.

Then if you do something like this:

```java
Parent parent = entityManager.find(Parent.class, 1L );
parent.name = "NewParentName";
parent.children.get(0).name = "NewFirstChildName";
entityManager.merge(parent);
```

So, due to the usage of `CascadeType.MERGE` in cascade you can expect that a child's name will be updated together with a parent's name.

Additionally (as it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade)), the `CascadeType.ALL` will propagate any Hibernate-specific operation, which is defined by the `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType` enum:

- `SAVE_UPDATE` - cascades the entity saveOrUpdate operation.
- `REPLICATE` - cascades the entity replicate operation.
- `LOCK` - cascades the entity lock operation.

So, if you are going to use else, for example, `session.saveOrUpdate(parent)`, then `CascadeType.ALL` will be a right chose here.

Anyway, you should review at first the operations list that you apply to the parent and want to propagate to the child, and then based on that make your choice.